# post $http request using file type input and get req.body and req.file not using multer nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, file, http

my tried code is :

```
//jade
 input(type='file', ng-model='filename',file-model='Image', required='')

 // controller.js
 $scope.reupload = () => {
      $scope.user = {
        UserName: 'sam',
        FirstName: 'sameer',
      };
      const fd = new FormData();
      $scope.theData = {};
      fd.append('file', $scope.Image);
      $scope.theData.i = fd;
      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/uploadresume',
        data: $scope.theData,
      })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(`error ${err}`);
        });
    };

//server.js
app.post('/api/uploadresume', api.UploadAlumniResume);

//api.js
exports.UploadAlumniResume = (req, res) => {
  console.log('req.body', req.body);
  console.log('req.file', req.file);
};
```

i am getting file data inito **$scope.Image**,

and i append the data  using of const **fd = new FormData()**.

fd as append the **$scope.Image**.

then store the **$scope.theData**  data to the post request.

i am getting result is:

// req.body $ req.file consoles

```
 req.body { i: {} }

 req.file undefined
```

I need to access  the req.body data and read and fs write the req.file data .

please give any solution to me !

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `FormData` inside an object that you're posting. It has to be the data itself.

```
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', $scope.Image);
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/uploadresume',
    data: fd,
    processData: false
  })
```

Comment: i am getting this error   " SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0 "

Comment: You can't put FormData in JSON. I'm not sure what you expect in `req.body`. You're not uploading anything other than the file.

Comment: i need to wirite the file path on this api so i need file data.

Comment: That's what `fd.append('file', $scope.Image)` does.

Comment: first i use to define the post request data as $scope image .the articale as use new FormData() to use file data to send  the fd as containg the new FormData()

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Angular, so I don't know how to do the `$scope` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

when you are image or file uploading , you need to pass header `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`

if you are using `bodyparser` , then body parser is not able to handle `form-data` , it is only handle `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json` data

as you getting  `req.file undefined` this because `bodyparser` not work with form-data

so use `multer` to handle `form-data`.

Comment: i need to wirite the file path on this api so i need file data . so i want file data in api only